# Display of images in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Following HTML-String is correctly displayed as an image in Chrome but will not shown in Firefox:

```
<img class="blog__entry__image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" alt="" style="background-image: url('/GBlog/content/images/post_images/28_09_2016_15_56_41_splist.png');">
```

The CSS-Class contains the following:

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: scroll;
border-image-width: 0;
border-style: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
box-shadow: none;
outline: none !important;
```

If I have multiple images of this setup then only the first one is not displayed.

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Is the `data URI` set at `src` of `<img>` at Question the complete text of the  `data URI`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes this is a server relative uri

Comment: What do you mean by "server relative uri"? How is the `data URI` created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gif data URL seems to be at fault in Firefox. Replacing it with a 1px x 1px transparent image/png URL:

```
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQImWNgYGBgAAAABQABh6FO1AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
```

where the PNG dataURL came from `canvasObject.toDataURL("image/png")` in Firefox, made the background image visible in testing.

**Update:** an image/gif data URL, obviously produced using different source file and conversion method than yours also works:

```
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
```